# Action of volume form on spinors in odd dimension

Tags: spin-geometry, clifford-algebras, spinor

We know that for a smooth orientable manifold of dimension $2n, i^n$ times the volume form acts as identity on the positive spinors and acts as minus identity on the negative spinors via Clifford multiplication. I am looking for a reference: what's the Clifford action of the volume form on the spinors for a manifold of odd dimension. The literature seems to accept that for dimension $3$, the action of the volume form is minus identity (coming from the quaternions: $ijk=-1$).